# Matlab - plotting a circle with center visible

Tags: matlab, function, plot, geometry

I am interested in plotting a circle in Matlab but I want its center to be visible. As in I want its center to be marked by a dot. At the moment I am using the `scatter` function twice:

```
scatter(1,2,1000,'r') # plots the circle
hold on
scatter(1,2,10,'r','filled') # plots the centre (as a very small circle
    # so it appears like a dot)
```

I am wondering is there a built-in function that exists that would enable me to do that in only one step? Plot a circle with its centre visible?

Many thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is probably one of the best ways to do it.  Do you have a reason for not wanting to split this up into two statements?

Comment: It would make my code more readable and clearer. More efficient @rayryeng

Comment: What quantifies having two separate statements to plot two separate objects less efficient than doing it in one line?  Do you have some sort of tool or measuring scheme to assess that kind of performance?  Also, working with what David Kelley said, you have to plot two separate objects - you don't have a choice.

Comment: Ah ok thaks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You can display the [Unicode character U+2609](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2609/index.htm), which incorporates the circle and the dot in a single character.

Since that number 2609 is hexadecimal, you need to convert from hex string to decimal number with [`hex2dec`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html), and then interpret that decimal number as a Unicode character with [`char`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html). That character can then be shown on the current axis using [`text`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html). It can also be used in figure title, axis labels etc, juyst like any other string.

For repeated use, define the character in a variable

```
dotcircle = char(hex2dec('2609'));
```

and then you can use it conveniently. For example:

```
axis([0 1 0 1])
title(['Example with character "' dotcircle '"'])
text(.25,.25, dotcircle, 'fontsize',20, 'color',[.3 .3 .3])
text(.5,.5, dotcircle, 'fontsize',40, 'color','r')
text(.75,.75, dotcircle, 'fontsize',60, 'color','b')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there to be a built-in function to do so but you could easily write one:

```
function drawMyCircle(x, y, cirlce_r, center_r, color)
hold on;
scatter(x, y, circle_r, color);
scatter(x, y, center_r, color, 'fillled');
hold off;
```

If you're concerned about performance, this is about as good as you can get - Matlab still has to plot two separate objects to get this done.